# Not getting likes on my webpage from facebook page

Tags: html, css, facebook

I just created a simple webpage to put like box on the webpage.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


LIKE BOX BELOW

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/kiet.infocenter" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to place a like box which shows the pics of people who like it.
But I cannot see any like box .What is wrong?

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem
It now shows up on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsaneCoder/Vt7mw/) but not on my localhost machine,even when I keep refreshing the webpage.Why?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** 
Comment from original poster: 
`You have to first create a unique user name for the page in order to use it.`
It turns out for the like-box you need to include a little more JavaScript, which can be seen here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

The reason your like-box is not showing up now is because you are on `localhost` and Facebook needs to access your page to have the box appear.  It cannot access the page if it is `localhost`, which is why it does work on jsFiddle.

**Original Post** 
You have the wrong `div` for the like code.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/GNJ4V/

### Correct HTML

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/kiet.infocenter" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```

Comment: :Actually I don't want the like button,but the like box which also shows the pics of the people who like it.

Comment: Hmm well the like-box says you need to `Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening <body> tag.`  Have you done that with your current code?

Comment: :No . How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/  I think the like-box requires more javascript than just the like-button, which is why the button is showing up on jsFiddle and not the box.

Comment: :I thimk the answer is here.When I go [http://https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/] and  type `www.facebook.com/quizzaster` in Facebook page url,it shows up the like box.But when I type `www.facebook.com/kiet.infocenter` no box shows up.(kiet infocenter is my page).I think I am picking the wrong page .Can you help what is exactly that URL?

Comment: I found the problem.You have to first create a unique user name for the page in order to use it.That's it. **But now it shows on jsfiddle and not on my system.Why?**

Comment: Are you posting this on an actual web page or just local to your system?  If you are running it on localhost then the facebook plugin will not work.  It works on Fiddle since it can be reached via the web.

Answer (score 0):

You will be needing to get a like button code for your website. Use this website https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1308/How+do+I+add+a+Facebook+%22Like%22+button+to+my+homepage%3F

It will help you add a like button.